# Facebook Pixel giving "PageView" warning straight after insallation on Wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, facebook, pixel

As the title mentions I used the Wordpress plugin downloaded directly from my Facebook Pixel Events Manager page to install the Pixel on my site. However I cannot verify any activity on the site yet. 
I have downloaded and used the Facebook Pixel Helper plugin for Chrome as well which shows me this:

Pixel Helper Screenshot

[image]

I can't seem to find anywhere else online where someone has had and solved this issue and can't understand why it's happening.

Comment: So where does that “learn more” link take you to?

Comment: Just to a Pixel Helper troubleshooting page that doesn't seem to have any solution on it. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-pixel/support/pixel-helper#did-not-load

Comment: ourtoptowns.com the site in question? Only place I see such an error is on the contact us page, and there its for a Lead track, not PageView. That particular `fbq` call seems to be wrapped in document.ready, whereas the others are just “normally” placed in script elements to directly execute at that point.

Comment: Okay, that's interesting. I'm sorry for sounding so confused, but is there anything would you recommend?

Comment: Not sure if that second code block was output by the plugin as well, or if that was inserted manually? If the former, you should probably talk to the plugin author.

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure either. The thing is though, I've also tried manually installing the javascript code snippet into the site header without any plugins active and I get the same error.